# Multiple build variant targets

Tags: makefile

I'm building firmware binaries that need multiple variants. There are `#ifdef`s in the code for different generations of the board, different peripherals and different parameters. So I have filenames like `foo-REVC-LCD-EUR.elf` for the European version of the board that has an LCD and is rev. C of the hardware.

I'm trying to reduce boilerplate in the makefile. Right now, it looks something like this:

```
all: foo.elf \
  foo-DEBUG.elf \
  foo-LCD.elf \
  foo-LCD-DEBUG.elf \
  target_unit_tests.elf

foo%elf: \
  bar.ao \
  baz.ao \
  banana.ao

target_unit_tests.elf:  \
  bar.ao \
  bar_tests.ao \
  baz.ao \
  baz_tests.ao\
  banana.ao \
  banana_tests.ao

# linker
%.elf: %.ao startup_stm32f0xx.ao system_stm32f0xx.ao
    $(ARM_CC) $(ARM_FLAGS) $other_arguments -o $@ $^

# compiler, general case
%.ao: %.c
    $(ARM_CC) $(ARM_CPPFLAGS) $(ARM_FLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

# compiler, build variants for `foo'
foo-%.ao: foo.c
    $(ARM_CC) $(ARM_CPPFLAGS) $(ARM_FLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

# combinatorial explosion
foo-DEBUG.ao: ARM_CPPFLAGS += -DDEBUG
foo-LCD.ao: ARM_CPPFLAGS += -DLCD
foo-LCD-DEBUG: ARM_CPPFLAGS += -DLCD -DDEBUG
```

The targets contain flags in their names. How can I replace the last three rules (these are multiplying fast) with a single one that extracts flags from the target name?

Or am I going down an insane path and need to rethink my strategy?

Comment: To add to MadScientists answer, you may take a look at [the GNUmake table toolkit](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) which was written with metaprogramming and project management of some sorts in mind.

Comment: This makefile is not right.  There's no target that depends on `foo-DEBUG.ao` etc. so they will never be built.  There's no recipe for building any of these `.ao` files.  The target depends on prerequisites like `bar_tests.ao` which are not defined as targets anywhere.  It may seem like this are nitty things but in reality they're critical, because without understanding how these are to be used we can't give you advice on how to structure your makefile.  In general, you want to use automatic variables like `$@` or `$<` or `$*` to extract the variable part of the name.

Comment: Indeed, this is a fragment of the makefile, and one that's in development at that. I've added a few more lines to the question, hope that clarifies it. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty open-ended question, which is not usually approved of on StackOverflow.  However to get you started:

First, it's best to build your makefile to place all the generated per-target files into a separate directory for each target.  Generated common files (if any) can be placed into a common directory.

Second, consider as much as possible defining your builds by setting variables, then writing generic rules that use these variables.  This will allow you to create and modify variants by changing the values of variables, without having to mess with complicated rules.

To accomplish this you might take a look at the [Metaprogramming Make](http://make.mad-scientist.net/category/metaprogramming/) blog post series (start with the last one listed, which is the first one written) and consider how capabilities such as constructed macro names can help your situation.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for the link again. It was going pretty pretty well, until it suddenly got all Lispy at the end, I was not expecting that! ![apply eval](https://sicp.comp.nus.edu.sg/chapters/img_javascript/sicp.png)

Comment: Having read your meta-making posts, I edited my question to be more specific.